# what does the word "on" prefix mean in program

Tags: c

When I read some program write with C language, I find some function name have the word "on" as a prefix, such as on_something(). So what does the word "on" stand for? If you can tell me some links or books about this,it will be better. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is just a naming convention. Call this function on some event, like `on_load`, `on_entry`, `on_exit`. There is nothing special about these functions.

Comment: it confused me for a long time. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

It means "when this thing happens". It's a *reasonably* common usage in English, but I can see how it would be confusing for developers who don't have English as a first language.

As an example outside computing, you might say, "**On entry** to a country, you must present your passport" or equivalently "You must present your passport **on entry** to a country."

Comment: Yes,it's very confusing for me.You are so smart.Thank you for understanding me.I think I should learn more English culture and background knowledge.So are there  any other similar usage just like word "on"?

Comment: @user7625313: I'm not sure what you mean by "other similar usage just like word on" - there are lots of naming conventions, some of which are common across programming languages and some of which aren't.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an abbreviation. The word "on" is a naming convention to indicate that the function is called when an event occurs. E.g. "onKeyPress" means this function is called when a key is pressed.

Possible duplicate: [What does the prefix “on” in a function (e.g.“onButtonPressed”) mean?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/299101/what-does-the-prefix-on-in-a-function-e-g-onbuttonpressed-mean)

Comment: Get it, your link is very clear.Are there any other similar naming conventions?

Comment: Vary from language to language. Examples in Java, `emit` (e.g. `emitSomeEvent`). `add` and `remove` (e.g. to add an item or a handler). `get` and `set` (to set a property), `is` for a boolean property.

Comment: so what does "emit" means here?

Comment: `emit` is the initiator of `on`. That is, the function that will call the `on` methods of all the registered listeners will be called `emit`.

Comment: I think the verb  like add or remove is easier to understand than preposition. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I guess in this case it's hard to come up with a useful verb because the event emitter shouldn't know or care what you want to do with the event. I suppose `handle` could be used but that word is longer and has other meanings.